# Inverse limit of the following system.

Tags: number-theory, limits, ring-theory, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_L = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ be the number ring of $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$, and $\mathfrak{p} =(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ a prime (and maximal ideal) in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

What is the inverse (projective) limit of the following,

$$\mathcal{O}_{L,\mathfrak{p}} = \lim\substack{\leftarrow \\ n} (\mathcal{O}_L /\mathfrak{p}^n).$$

I think it is $\mathcal{O}_L$ but this is purely intuition.

Comment: Given that $\mathfrak{p}^2=(2)$ we get that
$O_L/\mathfrak{p}^{2n}$ is the free $\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$-module with basis $\{1,\sqrt{-5}\}$. As the inverse limit of $\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$ is the ring of $2$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_2$, it looks like the limit should be $\Bbb{Z}_2[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Thanks this seems good reasoning, I will go over the steps.